# Different results when sending via UDP

Tags: c++, sockets, udp

I am writing a program for video transmission - it uses OpenCV for splitting video into frames and then sends them via UDP.

Problem is - when I send I get different results - sometimes only few frames are sent, sometimes they are corrupted. It is weird because I am sending to localhost (127.0.0.1) and there should not be any data loss.

I am sending frames by chuncks, size of each chunk is 10240 bytes.

I also use Winsock 2 with blocking sockets.

What can be a root cause of this problem?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7968907/214671.

Comment: Yes, but when I am trying to perform communication via TCp it works really slow.

Answer (score 1):

You *are* aware that the `U` in `UDP` stands for unreliable, yes? No, not really, but it's a good way to remember that the protocol doesn't guarantee delivery.

If you need guaranteed delivery, you should be using `TCP`.

Comment: UDP: User Datagram  Protocol, but indeed it's not reliable.

Comment: Or add sequence numbers to the user protocol.

Comment: All you need to know right there in Pax's answer. No guaranteed delivery unless you write the layer yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The first few results from https://www.google.com/search?q=udp+localhost+packet+loss suggest you can lose packets even when sending to localhost.