# Regarding thread priorities in C

Tags: c, multithreading

I am developing a multi threaded application in C. In my application there are 40 threads which receives the UDP packets from 40 different ports and place the data into the queues (40 queues for 40 ports). Now there are another 40 data processing threads which takes the data from the respective queues and process them. The current scheduling of policy of my threads are `SCHED_OTHER`.

The problem is that some port listening threads are missing the packets. What can I do to solve this problem. I have some solutions in my mind:

a) Making the data reading threads real-time. How can I make it? (Will it starve the data processing threads from CPU?).

b) Increasing the nice level of my whole application (it is not solving the problem).

c) ?

I am using Pthreads.

Comment: "Missing packets". Even with the buffering in kernel? Have you determined how long your packet reading is being starved of execution?

Comment: I don't know how to find the "starvation of execution".  How I can buffer in kernel?

Comment: try increasing the socket buffer size. See this question and answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968566/what-would-cause-udp-packets-to-be-dropped-when-being-sent-to-localhost

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is, how have you determined your problem is down to your threads not executing to read a packet. 'Cos my gut feel is that that is not your issue...

Comment: Dear Joe, When I decrease the number of threads the system is running fine. So My feeling is that increasing the number of threads to 40 is causing the problem. How can I find that whether the thread is not executing the read a packet or is there any thing else (socket buffer size) as sigismondo suggested.

Comment: Dear Sigismondo, Thanks for your answer, I am gonna check it.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Seems a bit of a strange design.  40 threads to read 40 ports, OK, but 40 queues with 40 processing threads?  Probably not a big issue, assuming that the queues are 'real' producer-consumer queues, ie. block on empty, but still sounds a bit 'off' to me..  Please say that you are not using some nasty 'non-blocking' queue design:)

Comment: How much time does the processing threads consume to extract the packets? How many packets arrive at every port? Maybe you should consider having 1 thread listening all ports at every time

Comment: Oh - another thing - your queues - they are queueing buffer pointers, yes?  Not copying in/out all the data inside a lock?